# ReactJS with CoffeeScript with Rails ReferenceError: <component> is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, reactjs

I just started learn ReactJS and from the very start I have problem!
As I can see you say that React working with coffee.
my file hello.js.jsx.coffee

```
HelloWorld = React.createClass
  render: ->
    `<div>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>`
```

and in my view:

```
= react_component('HelloWorld', {}, :span)
```

But I get error:

> ReferenceError: HelloWorld is not defined

sample of my app is:

https://github.com/olegsobchuk/example_app

I'm using Rails 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found resolve

instead

```
HelloWorld = React.createClass
  .....
```

we have to use

```
@HelloWorld = React.createClass
  render: ->
    `<div>
       <h1>Hello World!</h1>
     </div>`
```

Thanks [@rmosolgo](https://github.com/rmosolgo) !